# Python: How to convert datetime-ticks on an x-axis to just hours?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

So I have seen a lot of similar problems searching google, but none quite like mine.

I plottet some data and I used datetime-objects on my x-axis. It now looks like this:
[image]

The datetime-objects show date and time(hour). So this shows data from March 2nd from 2pm to 20pm.
What can I do to "convert" it to just show the hours and no dates? And what can I do to change the ticks to let them show for example 15, 18 and 21pm?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

(Edit)
My code to plot this looks like this:

```
#X-(a DataFrame-column of datetime-objects) and Y-values (a DataFrame-column with integers) that are to be plotted: 
    x_values = values["DateTime"]
    y_values = values["attributes.count"]
```

DateTime and attributes count are sotred in a DataFrame like this: 
[image]

Comment: Its always good to show your code so we can see how you're doing it.

Comment: Have a look at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html